# How to wait Func<T>().Invoke

Tags: c#, func

I have a method to show loading form with parameter `Func<T>` and in that method I use func.Invoke(); this.Close();

but in this cast this.Close(); not waiting for func.Invoke to finish.

Help me please.

```
private void ShowLoading<T>(Func<T> func)
{
    func.Invoke();

    this.Close();
}

private void Button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ShowLoading(() =>
    {
        Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(".\\sqlexpress", "sa", "underadmin"));
        Backup backup = new Backup() { Action = BackupActionType.Database, Database = "TestMedia" };
        backup.Devices.AddDevice(@"D:\BACKUP\TestMedia.bak", DeviceType.File);
        backup.Initialize = true;
        backup.PercentComplete += Backup_PercentComplete;
        backup.SqlBackupAsync(server);
        return 0;
    });
}
```

Comment: You can't `await` a function that is not `async`. Make `func` async (i.e.: Func<Task<int>> func) and you'll be able to `await` it.

Comment: @Viko This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The question in its current state is also incomplete and therefore unclear. Read [ask] and then edit the question to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that can be used to reproduce the problem, allowing a better understanding of what is being asked.

Comment: Have you considered changing `Backup_PercentComplete` (or even better, a method the subscribes to `Backup.Complete`) so **it** does the `this.Close()` (rather than `ShowLoading` doing it)?

Comment: @Viko https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms202914%28v%3dsql.105%29

Comment: `Func<T>.Invoke()` will not return until the code it refers to returns, there's no *need* to wait for it because you can't, and you shouldn't. Instead, focus on the code it refers to complete before it is complete. Most likely the `BackupAsync` call in there starts a backup, and you're observing that you close the form or whatever before it is done, then you need to figure out how to wait for the backup to complete.

Comment: Thank u all guy, Now I have a solution. Just change backup.sqlBackupAsync to backup.sqlBackup and then I in method ShowLoading I make a new BackgroudWorker in DoWork I add fucn.Invoke(); then in DoWorkCompleted I call this.Close(); work fine :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank u all guy, Now I have a solution. Just change backup.sqlBackupAsync to backup.sqlBackup and then I in method ShowLoading I make a new BackgroudWorker in DoWork I add fucn.Invoke(); then in DoWorkCompleted I call this.Close(); work fine :)

```
private void Button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ShowLoading(() =>
        {
            Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(".\\sqlexpress", "sa", "underadmin"));
            Backup backup = new Backup() { Action = BackupActionType.Database, Database = "TestMedia" };
            backup.Devices.AddDevice(@"D:\BACKUP\TestMedia.bak", DeviceType.File);
            backup.Initialize = true;
            backup.PercentComplete += (s, ev) => lblPercent.Text = ev.Percent.ToString();
            backup.SqlBackup(server);
            return 0;
        });
    }

    private void ShowLoading<T>(Func<T> func)
    {
        var bgk = new BackgroundWorker();
        bgk.DoWork += (s, e) => func.Invoke();
        bgk.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, e) => this.Close();
        bgk.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Make your click handler async and set a TaskCompletionSource in the delegate.

In order to do this, you must define the delegate as `Func<Task<int>>` since all awaitable methods have to return a `Task<>` of some kind.

```
private async Task ShowLoading(Func<Task<int>> func)
{
    await func.Invoke();

    this.Close();
}

private async void Button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await ShowLoading( () =>
    {
        var source = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
        Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(".\\sqlexpress", "sa", "underadmin"));
        Backup backup = new Backup() { Action = BackupActionType.Database, Database = "TestMedia" };
        backup.Devices.AddDevice(@"D:\BACKUP\TestMedia.bak", DeviceType.File);
        backup.Initialize = true;
        backup.PercentComplete += Backup_PercentComplete;
        backup.Complete += (s,e) => { source.SetResult(0); };
        backup.SqlBackupAsync(server);
        return source.Task;
    });
}
```

But a far simpler way to do it would be just to handle the `Complete` event with the close action.

```
private void Button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(".\\sqlexpress", "sa", "underadmin"));
    Backup backup = new Backup() { Action = BackupActionType.Database, Database = "TestMedia" };
    backup.Devices.AddDevice(@"D:\BACKUP\TestMedia.bak", DeviceType.File);
    backup.Initialize = true;
    backup.PercentComplete += Backup_PercentComplete;
    backup.Complete += (o,e) => { this.Close(); };
    backup.SqlBackupAsync(server);
}
```

Comment: await backup.SqlBackupAsync(server);
Can't await void :) that error on designtime

Comment: `SqlBackupAsync` is an EAP asynchronous method, ie its a void and uses events

Comment: Plus one for the `TaskCompletionSource`

Answer (score 0):

One option to consider is to add a new method which is called when the backup is [completed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.backuprestorebase.complete?view=sql-smo-140.17283.0) - and it is **that method's** responsibility to call `this.Close`.

You do this in a similar way to what you do with `PercentComplete`:

```
backup.PercentComplete += Backup_PercentComplete;
```

So it would be:

```
backup.Complete += Backup_Complete; // or whatever you want the method to be called:
```

*`Backup_Complete` will have the `this.Close;` line of code there, rather than in `ShowLoading`.*